# How to fix "Unhandled Rejection (Error): not supported" error in React+Cloud Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a Cloud Firestore database with the following query:

```
db.collection("shops").where("email", "==", user.email).get()
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

I have written code in the "catch" block in order to handle a promise rejection, but I am getting the following error by invoking ".get()"

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): not supported
```

I have looked up this error online and there does not seem to be anybody asking about this kind of error. Does anybody have an idea as to what could be causing this? I have done all of my firebase/firestore queries according to official documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that there's another Promise in your code that doesn't have a catch?

Comment: It is erroring explicitly on this line of code. Any other promises in the code were fine before inserting this line.

Comment: Just to make sure - you're passing a function to `catch`, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Which Firebase SDK are you using? I was getting the same error on a Node application using Firebase-Admin, but because I was using domino to create a Window object it would fail since it was checking to see if it was running in on Node by checking if global.window.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [#1445](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1455), in my case I had to do the following:

1. Open `node_modules/protobufjs/src/util/minimal.js`.
2. Change the following line `util.isNode = Boolean(util.global.process && util.global.process.versions && util.global.process.versions.node);` to `util.isNode = true;`.

Comment: That seems like a very temporary fix, especially as node modules aren't committed to repo.

Comment: @Mendel indeed, that's why I created my fork of this repo and getting the correct file in such a way (as described in the issue #1445):

My final solution was to change this simple line, and upload it to a separated repo (https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire). Then in package.json do that way "protobufjs": "https://github.com/danieldanielecki/protobufjs-angularfire". You can of course upload it on your GitHub, and link it from there.